# How to let inline functions from different classes call each other

Tags: c++, syntax, inline

To make some core-codes run as fast as possible, I want to make three functions inline, those belong to two classes respectively.

Ideally, I want to define them as following:

```
class ClassB;
class ClassA {
    ClassB * pB;

    inline void func1() {
        // do something
    };

    inline void func2() {
        pB->func3();
    };
};

class ClassB {
    ClassA * pA;

    inline void func3() {
        pA->func1();
    };
};
```

I know it's impossible if I simplly code as above.
My question is : Is there a way in it, we can do similar things?
At least, let them run as fast as possible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the functions outside the class definitions and still `inline` them.

```
class ClassB;
class ClassA {
   ClassB * pB;

   void func1();

   void func2();
};

class ClassB {
   ClassA * pA;

   void func3();
};

inline void A::func1()
{
   // do something
}

inline void A::func2()
{
   pB->func3();
}

inline void B::func3()
{
   pA->func1();
}
```

I am not sure how the compiler will generate code for mutually referencing `inline` functions but they are fine from a synactic point of view.

Comment: Correct. Also if you use LTO then this is possibly done for you so the whole thing may be moot

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Your suggestion is what I want to get!
But would it really be implemented as INLINE by compilers(gcc-8.2.0 is mine)? Is there a simple way to confirm it?

Comment: @Leon, I am not literate in assembly code. You will have to figure out what the compiler does by looking at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry, what is "LTO"?

Comment: @Leon Link-time optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make members public if you want to call them from outside the class.

The functions you call must be defined prior to where you call them.  You can achieve this by defining some functions outside the class :

```
class ClassB;

class ClassA
{
    ClassB * pB;

    public:
        void func1()
        {
            // do something
        };

        void func2();
};

class ClassB
{
    ClassA * pA;

    public:
        void func3() 
        {
            pA->func1();
        };
};

inline void ClassA::func2()
{
    pB->func3();
};
```

Also note that using the `inline` keyword is not necessary when you define the function inside the class.

Comment: I'd take a consistent approach if you can because this is already quite hard to read.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, It is consistent - only move what's necessary out of the class body.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Your suggestion is what I want to get!
But would it really be implemented as INLINE by compilers(gcc-8.2.0 is mine)? Is there a simple way to confirm it?

Comment: @Leon, it is up to the compiler to decide what is actually inlined.  The `inline` keyword is more like a hint to the compiler.

Comment: It is only required that the functions are declared before they are called (or declared inside the same class scope): https://godbolt.org/z/dFNOWA. The `inline` keyword is mostly required to fulfill the one-definition-rule. (And compiler may take it as a hint, but don't have to)

Comment: @chtz thanks! the URL is very valuable!

Comment: "The inline keyword is more like a hint, instead of a directive". In fact, what i want to figure out is whether the two ways equivalence or not? I always worry about it would not be implemented as inline really, not same as them be inside the class body.

Comment: @Leon Putting a member function definition inside a class definition, and putting it outside the class definition but marking it `inline`, are completely identical (in this sense). Whether or not actual inlining will occur is completely out of your hands.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit   OK, thanks.